# What is done here. What does this syntax means in sightly?

Tags: aem, sightly

[I am reading the docs about calling clientlibs in sightly](http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/htl-clientlibs/).
I am not getting the below syntax

```
<sly data-sly-use.clientlib="/libs/granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html"
     data-sly-call="${clientlib.all @ categories='clientlib1,clientlib2'}"/>
```

why we are using category here? How does it related to clientlibs?

Comment: Pls go through this code `/libs/granite/sightly/templates/ClientLibUseObject.java`

Comment: The documentation for Client-Side Libraries is available at https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/the-basics/clientlibs.html. This will hopefully provide you with enough information as to why you need to specify the categories to be loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets break this down:

**`<sly>`** - is a sightly tag that does nothing :) So when you don't want to use an HTML tag you can use `<sly>` as a placeholder.

**data-sly-use.clientlib="/libs/granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html** - this line references the clientlib.html file that has templates marked with `data-sly-template` attributes. These templates are reusable piece of markup. Look at them as functions in htl.

**`data-sly-call`** - used to call one of the templates from the above clientlib.html

**clientLib.all** - "*all*" is the name of the template being called from clientlib.html which is referred using clientLib keyword (-use.clientLib)

**@ categories='clientlib1,clientlib2** - categories are used to identify cq:clientLibraryFolder that are used for client side code in AEM. If you check http://localhost:4502/libs/granite/ui/content/dumplibs.html it will show you the location of libraries clientlib1 & clientlib2

So in a nutshell, this line calls 2 libraries (containing js & css) with categories clientlib1 & clientlib2 and loads them on to the page/component